# How to link image upload to strapi entry creation

Tags: reactjs, axios, multipartform-data, form-data, strapi

I'm doing a post request to my strapi and its working to some extent, but I'm not able to link my file (image) to the same entry creation. I only get the `formDataToSend` to show up in the strapi when I submit the form.

```
const [files,setFiles] = useState()

async function onSubmit(data) {
        setSubmitting(true);
        setError(null);


        let formDataToSend= {
            name: data.name,
            description: data.description,
        }

        axios.post(BASE_URL, formDataToSend)
        .then(res =>{
            console.log(res.data)
            return res.data.id
        })
        .then(refId =>{
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("files", files[0]);
            formData.append("refId", refId);
            formData.append("ref", "example");
            return axios.post(BASE_URL +"upload", formData)
        })
        .then(res =>{
            console.log("success", res.data);
            
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log(error)
        })
}

return(
<Form>
    <Form.Control type="file" {...register("image")}  name="image" onChange= 
    {(e)=>setFiles(e.target.files)} />
</Form>



)
```

When I log the response for both of them it shows the file is uploaded but it's not linked to this entry, and I can see it in the strapi media library as well.

```
{
id: "614104c3c3ded200165081f4"
mime: "image/jpeg"
name: "example_image.jpg"
provider: "cloudinary"
provider_metadata: {public_id: 'example_image', resource_type: 'image'}
related: []
size: 37.52
url: "cloudinaryurlexample.com"
}
```

```
{
description: "example description"
id: "614104c0c3ded200165081f3"
name: "example name"
}
```

any pointers to what I'm doing wrong and how to achieve this are really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to link uploaded files against a particular entry following parameters are mandatory:

###### Request parameters:

- **files** -  The file(s) to upload. The value(s) can be a Buffer or Stream.
- **refId** - The ID of the entry which the file(s) will be linked to.
- **ref** - The name of the model which the file(s) will be linked to (see more below).
- **field** - The field of the entry which the file(s) will be precisely linked to.

###### Solution to your problem:

As per the question you posted above, it's clear that you're missing the `field` key in your request params. This key should contain the column/field name of the collection where the uploaded file data will be linked.

###### Implementation:

```js
const [files,setFiles] = useState()

async function onSubmit(data) {
        setSubmitting(true);
        setError(null);


        let formDataToSend= {
            name: data.name,
            description: data.description,
        }

        axios.post(BASE_URL, formDataToSend)
        .then(res =>{
            console.log(res.data)
            return res.data.id
        })
        .then(refId =>{
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("files", files[0]);
            formData.append("refId", 1);
            formData.append("ref", "restaraunt");
            formData.append("field", "restaraunt_logo");
            return axios.post(BASE_URL +"upload", formData)
        })
        .then(res =>{
            console.log("success", res.data);
            
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log(error)
        })
}

return(
<Form>
    <Form.Control type="file" {...register("image")}  name="image" onChange= 
    {(e)=>setFiles(e.target.files)} />
</Form>

)
```

As per this, it will first upload the file to media gallery and then look for a collection called `restaraunt` and then update the data in the `restaraunt_logo` column/field of `restaraunt` collection.

###### Reference:

- [Upload files related to an entry](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/upload.html#upload-files)

Comment: I confirm that I use the same code and works, also check if you are using fetch that you don't define headers json...